# How to iterate the list and get the sentiments through pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

```
How to iterate the list and get the sentiments through pandas dataframe column?
```

I have one dataframe with only one column and only comments in that column.

```
data.head()
```

Output :

```
    Review
0   If you've ever been to Disneyland anywhere you...
1   Its been a while since d last time we visit HK...
2   Thanks God it wasn t too hot or too humid wh...
3   HK Disneyland is a great compact park. Unfortu...
4   the location is not in the city, took around 1...
```

I'm using hugging face sentiment classifier which returns the sentiment for the comment for example

```
classifier("My name is mark")
```

Output is :

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9953688383102417}]
```

To only get the label :

```
basic_sentiment = [i['label'] for i in value if 'label' in i]
basic_sentiment
```

Output is :

```
['POSITIVE']
```

**How to run all the given comments in the dataframe in the classifier and return the output?**

```
sent = []

for i in text[:]:
  sentiment = classifier(i)
  sent.append(sentiment)
```

I tried the above code, but's it's returning error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand your problem is iterating thorugh a pandas dataframe, not returning only `label` from the classifier.

If you want to return a list with the result of classifier() you'll need:

```
sent = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    sentiment = classifier(data.iloc[i,0])
    sent.append(sentiment)
```

`range(len(data))` iterates trough all rows of the dataframe. `data.iloc[i,0]` takes the value from the i-th row and the 0-th column (you only have one column and python is zero-indexed).

you could also save the result of classifier in another column so you have a dataframe with two columns, one contains the plain text, the other contains the sentiment:

```
# initialize new column
data['Sentiment'] = ''

for i in range(len(data)):
    data.iloc[i,1] = classifier(data.iloc[i,0])
```

Where `data.iloc[i,1]` targets the i-th row and the column with index 1 which is your second column (zero-indexing) `Sentiment`.

If you only want to save the `label` the you'll need insert that step into the code, however it's not really clear from you question what you want to save.